# External link to subdomain rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to link to an external page in Rails. I've seen several questions about this but none of the solutions are working for me.

I believe this is because the url is a subdomain (i.e. http://pages.foo.com/contact.html). This link is directing to http://www.foo.com/#!http://pages.foo.com/contact.html instead.

My `link_to` looks like this:

```
<%= link_to 'contact', 'http://pages.foo.com/contact.html', :class => 'contact pNav' %>
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What does the generated anchor tag look like in the page source code? Your use of `link_to` looks perfectly fine according to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), maybe you have some javascript on the page which is modifying the link click behaviour?

Comment: Generated anchor looks correct `<a href="http://pages.foo.com/contact.html" class="contact pNav">`. May be javascript causing the problem then?

Comment: I would think it must be if the html is correct. Without knowing your front-end stack I couldn't say what might be causing it, but I know that (for example) angularJS uses the `#` to separate its internal route params from the rest of the URL - maybe it's something similar to that?

Answer (score 0):

According to [rails apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

```
<%= link_to 'contact', 'http://pages.foo.com/contact.html', :class => 'contact pNav', :target => "_blank" %>
```